# How to convert time series data into image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have a dataset where I have 12000+ data points and 25 features out of which last feature is the class label. This is classification problem. Now, I want to convert every data points into image, . I have no idea how to do that. Please help. I work on Python. If anyone have could provide sample code I will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample of how data points look like or being stored and expected result in image form.

Comment: I have EEG dataset where the features are values of different waves like alpha, beta ect..and the last feature has value 0 or 1 which is the class label that I want to predict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already some work on that, you can use either Gramian Angular Fields (GAF) or Markov Transition Fields (MTF), a good description is in [Imaging Time-Series to Improve Classification and Imputation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00327). Also, some other works used recurrent plots as [Deep-Gap: deep learning framework](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07625). Imaging TS is an interesting way to think about them so you can use e.g. CNNs easily. But which method you like to use? BTW be aware this might not be an "efficient" way to classify time series :)

Comment: thank you for your response sir..sir I have EEG dataset where the features are values of different waves like alpha, beta ect..and the last feature has value 0 or 1. will the methods that you suggested above will make image for every datapoint?

Comment: The method can take in a vector which represents your data point and spits out a matrix which represents an image. So your 12000+ data points will be represented as 12000+ images. Then you can classify based on your labels.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir... one last question should I apply those methods for preparing images from EEG data??